# How to read from doc file and write into text file using java

Tags: java, docx, doc

I want to read text from doc file and write it into text file. How can I do it? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Mohit Singhal

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to handle Microsoft Office Documents. Apache POI will give you access to the text which you can then write to a simple text file using a FileOutputStream ([tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/) here).

Comment: Hi David, Can we do it without using external library ?